# How to use "find" combined with "grep" for specific information inside of files AND include the filename where the info was found?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I'm very familiar with using find coupled with -exec, in fact it's become one of my personal favorite BASH commands because of how cool it looks visually and how powerful and useful it can be.

I need to find a string contained within certain files on a VPS, the directory structure is far too massive for me to want to manually go through and find which files contain the string, so I figure its a perfect job for find -exec grep.

The full syntax of the command I have is as follows:

`find ./ -type f -name "*.*" -exec grep "section for more information." {} \;`

...and this works great for confirming that this string is in fact found within some files......but which ones? I would love to know if there is a syntax to display *which* files contain the string, preferably with the full path to them, although I guess it's not mandatory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `*.*` out of habit, or do you specifically only want to examine files which have a dot in their filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX `grep` will output the filename only when you specify multiple filenames. The typical trick is therefore to add `/dev/null` to ensure there's always more than 1:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.*" -exec grep "for more information." /dev/null {} \;
```

The GNU and BusyBox `grep`s additionally has a `-H` you could use:

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print the file name for each match.  This is the default
          when there is more than one file to search.
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about the matched lines themselves and just want the filename:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.*" -exec grep -q "for more information." {} \; -print
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Absolutely what I needed in every way! Thanks a ton for including the bit about the GNU and BusyBox version also, I often need the same thing on Android so this helps more than I can even explain!! Thank you!!

Comment: For efficiency, you'll want to use `find -exec grep 'regex' /dev/null {} \+` with a plus instead of a semicolon at the end, which runs as few `grep` instances as possible on a collection of files at a time (but isn't portable to traditional `find`). Reducing the number of processes can be quite impactful if you are scanning a large number of files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why accepted the above answer as it doesn't appear to solve your original ask, but this actually works.

```
find . -type f | while read f;do grep -q "for more information." $f && echo $f || true;done
```